# Apply crossbasis transformations in DLNM to holdout dataset

Tags: generalized-linear-model, out-of-sample, distributed-lag

I'm using the DLNM package in R to explore the use of distibuted-lag structures in otherwise-fairly simple linear models.  Id like to compare the performance of my model to other models using a holdout dataset, but am having difficulty taking my fitted models and computing estimates on the holdout dataset.

Here's a quick reproducible example:

```
library(dlnm)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

# Create some toy data; no dependence structure with neither the sales' own past values
# nor the lagged temperature values but should be good enough for anllustration 
trainData <- 
  data.frame(
time = 1:365,
temp = 50*sin(2*pi*1:365/365) + 50 + rnorm(365, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)) %>% 
  mutate(sales = 100 + 0.5*time #a time trend
     + (-0.5)*temp # when temp goes up, sales go down
     + rnorm(365, mean = 0, sd = 2) # a residual
  ) %>% 
  {.}

# Create a holdout dataset the model will NOT be trained upon.
# we're expected to generate predicitions given these covariate values (time, temp)
# and compare to actuals
testData <- 
  data.frame(
time = 366:425,
temp = 50*sin(2*pi*366:425/365)+ 50 + rnorm(60, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)) %>% 
  mutate(sales = 100+0.5*time #a time trend
 + (-0.5)*temp # when temp goes up, sales go down
 + rnorm(60, mean = 0, sd = 2) # a residual
  ) %>%
  {.}

# Create the crossbasis for the effect of temp on sales in the predictor- and lag-dimensions
cb.temp <- dlnm::crossbasis(
  x = trainData$temp, 
  argvar = list(fun = "lin"),
  arglag = list(fun = "poly", degree = 3))

# Fit a simple model
mdl <- glm(sales ~ time + cb.temp, data = trainData)

# Generate predictions on training dataset
trainData$preds <- predict(mdl, newdata = trainData, type = "response")
```

The code above generates some sample data, computes the cross-basis object for the temperature effects, and then make predictions on the training data.  Where I run into problems is in applying my model to a holdout dataset:

```
# Compute predictions on test set
# Fails because 'cb.temp' was built on the training data, has different dimensions

testData$preds <- predict(mdl, newdatra = testData, type = "response")


Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, preds, value = c(`8` = 75.2810932148823,  : 
  replacement has 358 rows, data has 60
```

Is there a recommended way to apply the transformations from an existing crossbasis object onto new data?

A few considerations:

1. If I re-create a new crossbasis in the test dataset, it will drop the first 7 values (because I specified the max lag to by 7).
2. If I combine the two datasets, compute a crossbasis from the entire 365+60 data points, and then separate back  into test+holdout datasets, is this acceptable?  Will this cause information from the test set to leak into my predictor?

Thank you!